# MongoDB C# official driver : Mapping objects to short names to limit space

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I searching a way to map the Bson objects defined using readable names ("category") to shorts names ("ct") and limit the space occuped by the items names in the main document base. I have seen this using others Drivers but what about using official Driver. How i can make, where is the best place to define. Can use longnames in queries and retrieve short contents?.

thanks.

Comment: Heh, you better hope you never have to go through the database. "Hmm. was ct Category or was it CustomerTab. Wait, what is the field `a`?" I think in 90% of cases this is premature optimization

Comment: I think if you have a record of the names you created for fields in your database stored somewhere safe, you're alright.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since nobody has actually given the answer to the question, here it is.

With the official driver you can do this by decorating a property name with BsonElement.  For example:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public BsonObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("dt")]
    public DateTime SomeReallyLongDateTimePropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

Now the driver will use "dt" as the BSON property name.

However, at this time there is no way to query using the POCO property name.  You would need to use "dt" in your queries.  There is a separate project that is built on top of the C# driver that provides LINQ style querying capabilities, but I have not tested it to verify if it will do what you are asking.

Comment: It's all good but, but all queries will work through short names. So you will forget after one hour what does following query mean:    Query.And(Query.EQ("fn", filter.Field1), Query.NE("ms", filter)) or somethong similar to this.

Comment: Agreed.. but if your collection is going to contain millions, or even billions of records (say for an analytics platform, for example) it would be worth it for you to keep some notes somewhere about what your property names are.

Answer (score 10):

It's better to keep models clean. And MongoDB.Driver allows to do it outside.

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<SomeClass>(x =>
{
     x.AutoMap();
     x.GetMemberMap(m => m.SomeReallyLongDateTimePropertyName).SetElementName("dt");
});
```

Comment: @ilans This code should be called only once, maybe in singleton configuration instance. 'x.AutoMap()' makes initial checks of all properties of 'SomeClass': detects data type, field name, etc and keeps only settings. Then you can override settings from previous step. In this example, 'SetElementName' asks mongo driver to use field name 'dt' instead of default name (SomeReallyLongDateTimePropertyName).

Answer (score 0):

Consider a record

{ last_name : "Smith", best_score: 3.9 }

The strings "last_name" and "best_score" will be stored in each object's BSON.  Using shorter strings would save space:

{ lname : "Smith", score : 3.9 }

Would save 9 bytes per document.  This of course reduces expressiveness to the programmer and is not recommended unless you have a collection where this is of significant concern.

Field names are not stored in indexes as indexes have a predefined structure.  Thus, shortening field names will not help the size of indexes.  In general it is not necessary to use short field names.

[check](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimizing+Storage+of+Small+Objects) source for more details

but other side is described in famous topic "[You saved 5 cents, and your code is not readable, congrats!](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/10/22/you-saved-5-cents-and-your-code-is-not-readable.aspx)"

**And my own opinion that short name is bad way.**

Comment: Have a sens but i use a collection where items names and sub items are always repeted with same information, the items names or key names. More than 70% are verbose information in place of value data. I think that maping have a true sens. See your data storage and bandwith that are not free.

Comment: While I agree that you do not want to sacrifice your code's readability, it is worth nothing that those 9 bytes will quickly add up in some cases. This answer is a bad one because while it is valid for a collection of 10 objects, it is going to hurt when dealing with a collection of 10 million. Disk space is cheap, but not free.

Comment: Disk usage is not even the biggest problem. Larger names will decrease the cacheability of the objects, both in RAM disk cache and in CPU caches. This greatly decreases performance, especially on magnetic disk drives, even for smaller datasets.